# Cross Tab PIVOT Query in Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

I have a table as below

```
CODE        PH_NUMBER     SUM(S.DURATION)   MIN(T.START_TIME)   CAMPAIGN
35039663    9250993319    120               19-Dec-17            297
35039725    917050139125  50                19-Dec-17            68
35039725    917050139125  370               19-Dec-17            297
35039726    919470833038  3370              19-Dec-17            68
35039726    919470833038  390               19-Dec-17            297
```

what I need is

```
code        Ph_number     sum(duration) Min(start_time) 297_count 68_count
35039663    9250993319    120             19-Dec-17          1       0
35039725    917050139125  50+370          19-Dec-17          1       1
35039726    919470833038  3370+390        19-Dec-17          1       1
```

how to achieve this in Oracle 11G? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of campaigns, or at least those you want to see, and thus a fixed number of columns in the result set? I'm guessing not, in which care you're looking at dynamic SQL. Or leaving it to a reporting layer to pivot, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You may easily use this by the charge of `sum` with `decode` ( no need to use `pivot` clause ):

```
select code, ph_number,
   sum(duration) "Total Duration", 
   min(to_char(start_time,'dd-Mon-yy')) "Min Start Time",
   sum(decode(campaign,297,1,0)) "297_count",
   sum(decode(campaign,68,1,0)) "68_count"
  from mytable
 group by code, ph_number
 order by code;
```

By the way, there's no problem to use column `ph_number` in `group by` expression, since its values are repeating for individual `code` columns.

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcab94/1)